# WHERE IN CURSOR : expected - got CURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why does the following code call in a function produce this error ?

```
SELECT table0.data
FROM table0
WHERE table0.id IN (SELECT cursor FROM dual);
```

While `SELECT cursor FROM dual` works on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While clients such as SQL*Plus and PL/SQL Developer are able to process a ref cursor returned from a query, like this:

```
select cursor(select 'X' as txt from dual)
from   dual;
```

a SQL `where` clause requires either an expression that resolves to a value or else a subquery, not a cursor expression:

```
select * from dual
where  dummy in 
       ( select cursor(select 'X' as txt from dual)
         from dual );

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-22902: CURSOR expression not allowed

select * from dual
where  dummy in ( cursor(select 'X' as txt from dual) );

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-22902: CURSOR expression not allowed
```

You get a similar error if you try to substitute a function that returns a ref cursor (here `testcursor()` is a function that returns a ref cursor):

```
select * from dual
where  dummy in testcursor();

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CURSOR
```

That just isn't something `where` clauses handle.

Comment: Nothing straightforward. You could write a pipelined table function to convert a refcursor to a collection.